# Pi Camera v2.1 not working

Tags: pi-3, camera, raspicam, pi-zero, pi-zero-w

I already checked out the other answers on StackExchange, and followed every step of this guide: https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/raspbian/applications/camera.md, as well as the referenced Setup guide.

Here is the output of `raspistill -v -o test.jpg` (same results with `sudo`):

```
mmal: Cannot read camera info, keeping the defaults for OV5647

raspistill Camera App v1.3.11

Width 2592, Height 1944, quality 85, filename test.jpg
Time delay 5000, Raw no
Thumbnail enabled Yes, width 64, height 48, quality 35
Link to latest frame enabled  no
Full resolution preview No
Capture method : Single capture

Preview Yes, Full screen Yes
Preview window 0,0,1024,768
Opacity 255
Sharpness 0, Contrast 0, Brightness 50
Saturation 0, ISO 0, Video Stabilisation No, Exposure compensation 0
Exposure Mode 'auto', AWB Mode 'auto', Image Effect 'none'
Flicker Avoid Mode 'off'
Metering Mode 'average', Colour Effect Enabled No with U = 128, V = 128
Rotation 0, hflip No, vflip No
ROI x 0.000000, y 0.000000, w 1.000000 h 1.000000
mmal: mmal_vc_component_create: failed to create component 'vc.ril.camera' (1:ENOMEM)
mmal: mmal_component_create_core: could not create component 'vc.ril.camera' (1)
mmal: Failed to create camera component
mmal: main: Failed to create camera component
mmal: Camera is not detected. Please check carefully the camera module is installed correctly
```

I see the error related to `ENOMEM`, but I double-checked my memory split has 256 (MB I assume) assigned to GPU.

Is my camera defective? How can I tell if I fried it? There has never been any sparks or pop or anything from static discharges. Unless my cat did it somehow...

**EDIT:** I tested this camera on a Pi 3, Pi Zero W (each with their respective cables), and on Raspbian Jessie and Stretch.

Comment: Sounds like a fried camera (given you've tested on multiple Pis). Incidentally, there wouldn't be any sparks or pops. Sensitive electronics like a camera can be fried with voltages way below that necessary to create a spark in the air.

Answer (score 2):

OK, looking at your raspistill output again I think the culprit is the "1:ENOMEM".  That in general C programming is an error that there's not enough memory.  Somewhere.  It's coming from mmal which I haven't dug into yet. but it could mean you have too much memory set to video memory so there's not enough regular, or the other way around.  mmal may run on the GPU or the CPU, I don't know yet.  You don't have memory hogs like Gimp or Firefox open when this happens by any chance?  Play with varying your memory split in raspi-config.  #7, A3, I run 64 for the GPU.  Top will show CPU free memory, I don't know how to check the GPU memory.  Funny the Zero's the same as the Pi though, one has 512 MB and the other has 1 GB.

Well, maybe, "failed to create component 'vc.ril.camera'" could still be a camera problem but the reason given is ENOMEM.  vc stuff is usually VideoCore.  I'm guessing you never played with the split and you've got like 16 for video.

Answer (score 2):

OK, see if http://ab1jx.1apps.com/ham/toys/picam/index.html#troubleshooting helps any.  With the 1.3 camera at least I do see the ENOMEM with the camera cable unplugged (or backwards).

You did enable the camera interface in raspi-config right?

It's the same error I get trying to run raspistill on a Pi that didn't even have a camera, but also has it disabled in raspi-config.  Backwards would be the same as not plugged in since backwards puts plastic (insulator) in contact with the connector's contacts.

Not that it matters but your original post says that the camera resolution is 2592x1944, that's what my version 1.3 is.

Answer (score 1):

Even simpler, the cable may be upside down.  There are only contacts on one side but it will plug in either way.  Just unplug it and turn it over.  Remember to unlatch and relatch.

Comment: I did check that actually, but thank you for the suggestion!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, looked like camera was faulty. In desperation I checked the continuity of the ribbon cable, all lines were open! Turned out to be a tiny hairline crack in cable near the termination, must have been bent too far. 
Cut the bad bit off with scissors, sandpapered the insulation till the metal conductors showed, glued the blue plastic back on the new end and plugged it in.
Working great, no more problems.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, my 1apps account vanished (free web page).  There's sort of a troubleshooting guide at https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/raspbian/applications/camera.md

There are 2 cables, between the Pi/Zero and the camera board, and between the camera board and camera.  Each gives certain errors when it's not plugged in correctly, both can be partly plugged in or crooked.  And the ones with circuit board foil on one side and plastic on the other have to be right side up or it's the same as not plugging them in at all.

I just got a v2 camera which worked yesterday, today it gives

```
mmal: Cannot read camera info, keeping the defaults for OV5647
mmal: mmal_vc_component_create: failed to create component 'vc.ril.camera' (1:ENOMEM)
mmal: mmal_component_create_core: could not create component 'vc.ril.camera' (1)
mmal: Failed to create camera component
mmal: main: Failed to create camera component
mmal: Camera is not detected. Please check carefully the camera module is installed correctly
```

I was working at the length limits of the cable, probably dislodged something.  I looked up the error for a clue as to which was unplugged and found my own post.

BTW the camera connectors on Zeroes especially fail easily and if you check one manufacturer's PDF (Molex) they rate the durability at 20 connect/disconnect cycles.  http://www.molex.com/webdocs/datasheets/pdf/en-us/0545482271_FFC_FPC_CONNECTORS.pdf and there's a thread on the Raspberry Pi forum about it https://lb.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=63&t=149795&sid=c4d3924bc028d2d810f10726c9628e9b

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and had troubleshooted a few things. It turned out the small connection between the camera lens and the camera board had come loose. Pushing it in tightly fixed it.